# Why would the resurrected Messiah eat ἰχθύος "ichthys" (fish) meat in [Luke 24:42-43], if YHVH was to restore Vegetarianism [Isaiah 65:25]?

Tags: luke, isaiah, messiah

We learn Jesus the Nazarene after being resurrected - eats ἰχθύος "ichthys" (fish) meat in [Luke 24:42-43] : "And they gave him a piece of a broiled fish, and of an honeycomb" (24:42  οἱ δὲ ἐπέδωκαν αὐτῷ ἰχθύος ὀπτοῦ μέρος καὶ ἀπὸ μελισσίου κηρίου) - "And he took it, and did eat before them." (24:43  καὶ λαβὼν ἐνώπιον αὐτῶν ἔφαγεν)

**However - YHVH speaking through the prophet Yeshayahu "Isaiah" says His Messianic Kingdom will be Vegetarian in [Isaiah 65:25]**

"A wolf and a lamb shall graze together, **[ and a lion, like cattle, shall eat straw ]** and a serpent-dust shall be his food; they shall neither harm nor destroy on all My holy mount," says YHVH". (זְאֵ֨ב וְטָלֶ֜ה יִרְע֣וּ כְאֶחָ֗ד וְאַרְיֵה֙ כַּבָּקָ֣ר יֹֽאכַל־תֶּ֔בֶן וְנָחָ֖שׁ עָפָ֣ר לַחְמ֑וֹ לֹֽא־יָרֵ֧עוּ וְלֹֽא־יַשְׁחִ֛יתוּ בְּכָל־הַ֥ר קָדְשִׁ֖י אָמַ֥ר יְהֹוָֽה)

**As a resurrected Messiah, Why would Jesus the Nazarene eat fish meat in contrast to Isaiah 65:25?**

Comment: In the present context, in the world as it is now, fish was eaten. The prophecy relates to a future re-arrangement on a new earth under new heavens.

Comment: As Nigel said, Some prophecies will be fulfilled at the 2nd coming. However, just because the animals are eating straw and living peacefully does not mean the Sons of God will eat straw.

Comment: After the second coming, there will be no death, and hence no meat consumption; (un)fortunately, the final judgment did not come immediately after the resurrection. :-)

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest that the prophecy of Isaiah 65:25 is not about vegetarianism but about peace and the absence of contention, as it is in Isaiah 11:6-9